# Docker Volume point to host Directory in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile :

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
USER jboss
RUN mkdir -p /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log
VOLUME /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log 
CMD /bin/bash
# CMD true
```

This resulting image is started with `docker run -ti --name=data_volume data/volume`. The next Dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
RUN sed -i 's|<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" 
    path="server.log"/>|\<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" 
    path="\${jboss.host.name}-server.log"/\>|' 
    /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

overrides the logging of the resulting jboss to log to "servername"-server.log in the logging dir. When I start the resulting image with `docker run -ti --name=wild-01 --volumes-from=data_volume my/wildfly` and `docker run -ti --name=wild-02 --volumes-from=data_volume my/wildfly` I have two log files in my data_colume container. So fine so good.

I would like to point my volume to a directory on the host eg. /var/log/wildfly.

How can I achieve this in Dockerfiles and not with the -v parameter when running `data/volume`

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to point my volume to a directory on the host eg. /var/log/wildfly.

remove all mention of volumes from your Dockerfile ... launch your container using

```
docker run -d -v /var/log/wildfly:/var/log/wildfly  your-image-name
```

then in your code just reference the normal path

```
/var/log/wildfly
```

Your syntax to launch the container using `docker run -ti` makes the container shell interactive whereas `-d` is the normal mode to spin it up as a daemon running in the background

Answer (score 1):

Inside dockerfiles you can only define volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. This is because every host can be different from the other.

Docker uses `/var/lib/docker` as "docker area" where it stores all docker-related data. It's the directory that's guaranteed on every host because it gets created on installation.

If you were to point out a volume in the dockerfile, let's say to `/home/mbieren/docker_vol`, the image would result in multiple errors when executed on a different host, as that directory does not exist and the user probably has insufficient permissions to create it.

Docker goes around that problem by not allowing custom mount-paths to be set in the dockerfile.